# SQL or LINQ: how do I select records where only one paramater changes?

Tags: sql, database, linq, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Say we have this list:

```
Id  IdRef   myColumn    anotherColumn
448    70      1            228
449    70      1            2s8
451    70      1            228
455    70      2            2a8
456    70      2            s28
457    70      2            28
458    70      3            v
459    70      3            28
460    70      4            22
461    70      3            54
462    70      4            45
463    70      3            s28
```

I need to select a list with a record everytime "myColumn" changes. So the result would be:

```
    Id  IdRef   myColumn    anotherColumn
448    70      1            228
455    70      2            2a8
458    70      3            v
460    70      4            22
461    70      3            54
462    70      4            45
463    70      3            s28
```

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem. In SQL, here is one approach to solve it using window functions:

```
select Id, IdRef, myColumn, anotherColumn
from (
    select t.*, lag(myColumn) over(partition by IdRef order by Id) lagMyColumn
    from mytable t
) t
where lagMyColumn is null or lagMyColumn <> myColumn
```

The inner query recovers the value of `myColumn` on the *previous* row, ordered by `Id`. Then the outer query filters on records where that value is different from the one on the current row.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=14951172b103d88f037021ca4ec9e758)**:

```
 id | idref | mycolumn | anothercolumn
--: | ----: | -------: | :------------
448 |    70 |        1 | 228          
455 |    70 |        2 | 2a8          
458 |    70 |        3 | v            
460 |    70 |        4 | 22           
461 |    70 |        3 | 54           
462 |    70 |        4 | 45           
463 |    70 |        3 | s28
```